# Is it possible to fake the data sent to an analytics server?

Tags: javascript

Let's assume I have a google analytics server tracking the users on my website. Is it possible, for a user to send fake data through the analytics? To be clear, I'm not asking whether we can detect bots that generate fake data. I'm asking if a user can fake the actions they take on my website?
For example, if I was tracking 5 objects on a page, and a user clicked on them in the order a>b>c>d>e, is it possible that they fake the data such that I observe something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The analytics server is just a common server receiving browser requests. Any user savvy enough to use *Developer Tools* on his browser can see the network requests and replicate them as they want.

The server usually will not validate if the browser or a script is sending data. The costs to implement hardened analytics is not worth it.

Comment: So, a user might detect the analytics script working in the background automatically, prevent it from sending the actual data and instead put in random data and send that instead?

Comment: Yes, if the user has a malicious intent. Most users will just block the script to prevent sending any data to the server.

Comment: @ThoriumBR how would one go about implementing hardened analytics to prevent such events?

Comment: You will not. Analytics are not usually hardened, the cost for that is high and the return is low. If you are thinking about hardening it, you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @ThoriumBR My use case is more about security rather than the standard analytics use case. I'm mostly interested in using analytics data to detect fraud in payment processes and making sure the data I get is correct is important here. If there are methods which can make sure I get correct data from a user it might be beneficial. I'd be grateful if you could point me towards any such methods Thanks.

Comment: This is why I told you are using analytics wrong. Fraud detection is a different kind of process, and analytics will not help. Fraud detection will use external tools, auditing, KYC forms, the like. Searching for *fraud detection in <enter your field here>* will give you lots of pointers. Getting correct data is less useful than you think, as a fraudster will probably supply correct data but with wrong motives.